# extract values from txt file and plot them in Linux

Tags: linux, text, extract

Now I have a txt file in Linux like this:

```
2003051612   2003051712   2003051812   2003051912

V3  3.915316e-08 4.081943e-08 3.427969e-08 3.008672e-08

V4  1.710598e-04 1.975139e-04 2.017657e-04 2.259201e-04

V5  1.231278e-01 1.256785e-01 1.234349e-01 1.222004e-01

V6  6.212954e-02 5.853570e-02 5.944641e-02 5.762145e-02

V7  3.982040e-01 3.950211e-01 3.965414e-01 4.031303e-01

V8  4.020746e-07 4.622676e-07 4.437724e-07 5.087076e-07

V9  2.773967e-01 2.829021e-01 2.840064e-01 2.709782e-01

V10 4.890398e-08 6.136693e-08 2.419245e-08 3.343889e-08

V11 1.382187e-01 1.370485e-01 1.357224e-01 1.451395e-01

V12 7.516122e-04 6.159778e-04 6.462624e-04 7.036210e-04

V13 4.329798e-11 5.468116e-11 5.090207e-11 5.232929e-11

2003052012   2003052112   2003052212   2003052312

V3  4.191380e-08 4.191363e-08 3.580984e-08 2.186910e-08

V4  1.514783e-04 1.514790e-04 1.291472e-04 1.856119e-04

V5  9.970667e-02 9.970649e-02 1.099325e-01 1.054409e-01

V6  6.082299e-02 6.082289e-02 5.988636e-02 5.233031e-02

V7  4.145499e-01 4.145499e-01 4.082337e-01 4.083575e-01

V8  5.506950e-07 5.506947e-07 5.075293e-07 3.205014e-07

V9  2.753448e-01 2.753447e-01 2.736255e-01 2.800287e-01

V10 2.621912e-08 2.621905e-08 2.500311e-08 1.655853e-08

V11 1.485740e-01 1.485743e-01 1.471598e-01 1.525930e-01

V12 8.495710e-04 8.495685e-04 1.032454e-03 1.063674e-03

V13 4.444214e-11 4.444189e-11 3.319341e-11 1.789053e-11
```

What I want to do is:

1. Sort the text file in order, like a table ( now it's just in plain txt format)
2. Extract the values for each parameters and plot them with time( for example, for V3 parameter, it has different values from date 2003051612 to 2003052312, I want ti plot V3 parameter values with dates.

I'm doing it under LINUX.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/), which is available for any Linux distro I can think of. It comes with a complete table tool (much like Microsoft Excel) that can import and export tabular data from txt files (look for "CSV import"), and can generate plots.

If that doesn't suit your needs, you could load the data using a few lines of python and generate plots, for example with the python library matplotlib, which feels a lot like the Matlab plotting routines.

Comment: The main problem is how t o extract the values I want and plots them. I'm not quite familiar with python or Matlab.

Comment: Then use LibreOffice Calc, like I said. It does the extracting for you when you import the data text file.